# use the selected item of a spinner

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, android-spinner

I am little bit stuck and need some ideas of how can I use the information that is selected from the spinner.
first the spinner is populated via Web service, by this code on the Asynctask:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                //Web service call
                transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION_BRING_NEEDS, envelope);

                //create SoapPrimitive and obtain response
                resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                int intPropertyCount = resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount();
                strNeeds = new String[intPropertyCount];

                for(int i= 0;i< intPropertyCount; i++)
                {                        
                    //Format the information from the web service
                    Object property = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(i);
                    if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
                        SoapObject needsList = (SoapObject) property;
                        strNeeds[i] = needsList.getProperty("Descripcion").toString();
                    }
                }
```

then on the postExecute I fill the spinner calling a method spinnerNeeds():

```
public void spinnerNeeds() {
        //Needs Spinner Control
        spnNeeds = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnNeeds);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strNeeds);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnNeeds.setAdapter(adapter);
        spnNeeds.setSelection(1);

        spnNeeds.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Todo
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
```

the thing is that the spinner is populated by the strNeeds[] with the property ("Descripcion"), but the web service response have 3 properties, and I need another property call "Codigo" so that information can be sended to another activity. How can I validate after choosing a option on the spinner that be validate with the "codigo" that I also need?

I was thinking on creating another String[] strCode  and save the property "Codigo" value inside the FOR() as I did with the "Descripcion" property... but if I pick an option on the spinner how can I validate that strCode??

PD: The "Codigo" property do not contain ascendance values, for example the first value is not 1,2,3,4.... they have random values...

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be quite complex, but once you understand it's very simple. 
First you'll need to create an object say, NEED with 3 properties(Description, Codigo..)
Next, instead of using an arrayadapter of type String, use arrayadapter of type NEED.
Next, in your custom class NEED, override the toString() method such that it returns the value of the property that needs to be displayed in the spinner.
Now, the selected item will return the NEED object, from which you get the value of the 'Codigo' property.

```
class Need{
String description, codigo, property3;
public Need(String desc, String codigo, String prop3)
{
 this.description = desc;//similarly for other 2 properties
}
@override
private String toString()
{
 return this.description;
}
}

strNeeds = new Need[intPropertyCount];
for(){
strNeeds[i] = new Need();
}

ArrayAdapter<Need> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Need>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     strNeeds);
```